# Find $\cos x$ via trigonometric addition formula in this rectangle.

Tags: trigonometry

> In rectangle $ABCD$, $G \in AB$, $F \in DC$, $E$ is the intersection point of $GF$ and $DB$. $|GB|=2$, $|BC|=|AG|=4$ and $|FD|=1$. $\measuredangle{GEB}=x$, Find $\cos x$.

[image]
My attempt: I drew a line that is perpendicular to $AB$ and passes through $F$. Let $T$ is the intersection point of them. I call $\measuredangle{DBA}=a$. So, $\measuredangle{FGA}=x+a$. We can say that $\cos{(\measuredangle{FGA})}=3/5$ because $|TG|=3$, $|FT|=4$, $|FG|=5$. I used cosine addition formula and got $15\cos x-10\sin x=3\sqrt{13}$. Should i make an effort to get $\cos x$ from this? I think there must be a simpler way. Thanks!

Comment: $\measuredangle{GEB}=x$ , but ithink you marked differently in the figure ?

Comment: Right. $\measuredangle{GEB}=\measuredangle{DEF}$. Should i edit it?

Comment: If it is logically correct then I think you don't need to edit.

Comment: Hint: Using the Pythagoras theorem you can find the sides $BD$ and $FG$. From similarity of the triangles $DEF$ and $BEG$ you can find the sides $DE$ and $FE$. And finally, from the cosine theorem you can find the $\cos{DEF}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec{DA}=\vec{u}$ and $\vec{DC}=\vec{v}$.

Thus, $$\cos{x}=\frac{\vec{DB}\cdot\vec{FG}}{|\vec{DB}|\cdot|\vec{FG}|}.$$
Now, $\vec{DB}=\vec{u}+\vec{v}$, $\vec{FG}=-\frac{1}{6}\vec{v}+\vec{u}+\frac{2}{3}\vec{v}=\vec{u}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{v}$, $|\vec{DB}|=\sqrt{(\vec{u}+\vec{v})^2}=\sqrt{16+36}=2\sqrt{13},$

$|\vec{FG}|=\sqrt{\left(\vec{u}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{v}\right)^2}=\sqrt{16+9}=5$ and 
$\vec{DB}\cdot\vec{FG}=16+18=34.$

Thus, $$\cos{x}=\frac{34}{2\sqrt{13}\cdot5}$$ or
$$\cos{x}=\frac{17}{5\sqrt{13}}$$
Another way.

Let $E\in{DC}$ such that $BE||FG$.

Thus, $\measuredangle DBE=x$, $DE=2$, $DB=\sqrt{4^2+6^2}=2\sqrt{13}$ and $BE=\sqrt{4^2+3^2}=5$.

Thus, by the cosine theorem for $\Delta DBE$ we obtain:
$$\cos{x}=\frac{DB^2+BE^2-DE^2}{2DB\cdot BE},$$
which gives the same result.